# Terraform Custom provider - Resource support error

Tags: go, terraform

I created a custom provider to use an internal API used for generating approved names for resources according to our standard. I wrote it with Go, but when I'm testing it, I'm getting an error saying:

***Error: meaningful_resource_name.server_name: Provider doesn't support resource: meaningful_resource_name***

Here's the test tf file I'm using:

```
resource "meaningful_resource_name" "server_name" {
    <... parameters ...>
}

output "server_name" {
    value = "${meaningful_resource_name.server_name.name}"
}
```

And this is the provider.go file:

```
package meaningful

import (
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform/helper/schema"
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform"
)

func Provider() terraform.ResourceProvider {
    return &schema.Provider{
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{},

        ResourcesMap: map[string]*schema.Resource{
            "meaningful_resource_name": meaningfulName(),
        },

        DataSourcesMap: map[string]*schema.Resource{},
    }
}
```

I already created a provider using this same structure, but I don't understand why it's not recognizing it. Any clues?

I'm using Go v1.10.4 and Terraform v0.11.10

Comment: If you have already made a provider using the same structure then it's probably a typo

Comment: Right, but where? Because following my code, there isn't any.

Comment: it's not really a "Stackoverflow" kind of question because you'd have to provide all of your source code.  And that wouldn't be a minimal example

Comment: The only practical "tip" I can think of is the (to me obvious) suggestion to cut out the stuff that isn't working, the test and the code, and then see if you get a different error or no error